# How to handle runtime exceptions that occur on a loading process delegated to newly spawned thread

Tags: java, multithreading, loading, resource-management, exceptions

I am looking to multi-thread the resource allocation routines (i.e world loading) in my game so that they can occur in the background whilst rendering a loading screen etc... The problem is, I used to have code like this (pseudo)

```
void foo()
{
    ...
    try
    {
        mWorld = world.create(...)
    } catch(EntityNotFoundException e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, now that the world is being loaded on another thread, I need to register a listener that will recieve notification when the world is ready. The problem is that if an exception occurs inside of the newly created thread, I cannot surround it in a try-catch like I have here. How is this problem solved?

I am thinking of having the loading thread interface with a handler that looks like this:

```
public interface IInitializationMonitor<T> extends IInitializationProgressMonitor
{
void begin();
void completed(T item);
void failed(Throwable error);
}
```

The problem being that error would need to be tested against multiple times with instanceof, or rethrown inside of a try block. I am curious if there is a more elegant solution...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interface will help here, when the call function of the Callable throws then the get of the Future will throw a `ExecutionException` where its cause is the original exception.

You can subclass [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) and override the `done` which will notify the world when the computation is either successful or failed and let the world handle the failure condition.